# Setting background of checkbox to white and remove grey unchecked checkmarks in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

When I set CheckBox in android to checked="false"  there is a greyed out checkbox and grayed checkmark that looks like it is already selected.  I don't want any checkmark at all to show, and no graying of the box.  Just a white box with no checkmark at all. Not even a grayed out one.

Answer (score 0):

First off it may not be a good idea to customize a check box, but if you need to do it you can create a button with two separate images for on/off png.  Then you set the checkbox drawable to be that button.